# tf.random.Normal() not generating different value

Tags: python, tensorflow, random, normal-distribution

I am trying to use `tf.random.normal(mean, stddev)` where both mean and stddev are like following

```
mean = np.array([0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8])
stddev = np.array([0.1, 0.08, 0.1, 0.15])
```

but for same pair the generated values are always same

```
tf.random.normal([1],mean,stddev, tf.float32).numpy()
```

for example,

```
array([0.52523446, 0.92018753, 0.52523446, 0.83785176], dtype=float32)
```

every time i run the outputs are different but the generated value for same parameters are always same.

I want to avoid getting  0.52523446 twice.
How can I ensure getting random results even if there are same mean, stddev pair mutiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
tf.random.normal([4],mean,stddev, tf.float32).numpy()
```

Yields:

```
tf.random.normal([4],mean,stddev, tf.float32).numpy()
Out[20]: array([0.48897663, 0.94428   , 0.4471385 , 0.8360004 ], dtype=float32)

tf.random.normal([4],mean,stddev, tf.float32).numpy()
Out[21]: array([0.7033355 , 0.93688935, 0.43403187, 0.5589987 ], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't know it would work this way.  Thanks for your answer. But what if I want multiple samples for each pair of mean and stddev?? Because if I use [4] with just one mean and stddev then it gives me 4 samples for that distribution .

Comment: Let's say you want 10 samples, then you can do this `tf.random.normal([10, 4],mean,stddev, tf.float32).numpy()`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/random_numbers). Instead of using `tf.random.normal`, set a RNG and then use it to get reproducible results and handle the behaviour of it. You can do something like that:

```
TF_RNG1 = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(seed=1312)  # Set the RNG for example in global scope.


def random_samples(num_samples): # Call this func whenever you want new samples from each distr.
    mean_ar = np.array([0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.8])
    stddev_ar = np.array([0.1, 0.08, 0.1, 0.15])
    a = np.empty([0, num_samples])
    for mean, stddev in zip(mean_ar, stddev_ar):
        a = np.vstack([a, TF_RNG1.normal([num_samples], mean=mean, stddev=stddev).numpy()])
    return a

example_1 = random_samples(num_samples=2)
example_2 = random_samples(num_samples=2)
```

Which returns two samples from each random distribution define from means and stddvs:

```
[[0.64746159 0.28875741]
 [1.07901216 0.96285772]
 [0.68051326 0.48751786]
 [1.10349631 0.70149976]]
[[0.52678907 0.34632182]
 [1.1144588  0.97134733]
 [0.5085696  0.70959347]
 [0.78321898 0.57734704]]
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/random_numbers and my own experience, `tf.random.normal` as well as any other APIs that used the old mechanism to generate random numbers are buggy and unreliable. `tf.random.Generator` is the new mechanism for generating random numbers. It internally used `tf.Variable` to make sure things work as expected.

You can vectorize the generation of random numbers from multiple normal distributions with different means and variances like this:

```
@tf.function
def vectorized_rand_gen(rand_gen,means,stds,n):
  return rand_gen.normal((n,)) * stds + means

rand_gen = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(8883)
means = tf.constant([5.0,10.0,5.0,1000.0])
stds =  tf.constant([1.0,2.0 ,1.0,4.0])

print(vectorized_rand_gen(rand_gen,means,stds,4))
print(vectorized_rand_gen(rand_gen,means,stds,4))
print(vectorized_rand_gen(rand_gen,means,stds,4))
```

Expected outputs:

```
tf.Tensor([   4.797662    11.434001     5.6649933 1000.5652   ], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([   4.5091076    9.176998     4.685211  1005.33514  ], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([   4.285514    8.202658    6.342854 1004.9558  ], shape=(4,), dtype=float32)
```